# В чем может быть дело, в форму передается не корректное значение

Tags: javascript, html

В чем может быть дело, если значение Type в форму передается так:

&type=Appartement%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09

Вот сам [проект](http://bot.immo/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/gnaax841/ код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

target срабатывает на элементе списка, $target.text() не вычищает пробелы, попробуйте заменить на `var $target = $(event.currentTarget).find('a');`

Comment: все сработало, спасибо за идею.